# Showing the a form below the textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

Hello I'm working on something for my thesis using Visual Basic 2005 I want the for to show below the textbox but I can get the exactly location of the textbox using Drawing Points.

Here's my code right now:

```
Dim x As Integer = Me.txtStockQUnit.Location.X + Me.Location.X + Me.grpMonitoring.Location.X
Dim y As Integer = Me.txtStockQUnit.Height + Me.txtStockQUnit.Location.Y + Me.Location.Y + Me.grpMonitoring.Location.Y
My.Forms.frmQuantityUnitDropListGrid.Location = New Point(x, y)
My.Forms.frmQuantityUnitDropListGrid.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

The location of controls on a form are relative to the top left corner of the form so you don't need to use Me.Location to position the textbox.

The following example sets the position of a textbox and the form on Form_Load:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'position a textbox on the form relative to the top left corner of the form
    txtStockQUnit.Location = New Point(100, 25)

    'position the form relative the top left corner of the primary display
    Me.Location = New Point(100, 300)
End Sub
```

Note: A textbox can only be placed on the form surface not in 'mid air'.

Comment: I tried the code it works really great but my problem is that the textbox is from another form then there's another form which will show up when the event on the textbox occurs which is GOT_FOCUS that form will show below the textbox...I used location to point the forms position but it cant locate the textbox I also set the form startup position to manual still not wont work.. any Ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Just found it on the net and is working as what I want.

```
Dim ctl as Textbox 'the textbox which the form will show at its bottom
Dim ctlpos As Point = ctl.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0)) 'Point.Empty is not function so se Point(0, 0)

Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual 'set it to manual
Me.Location = New Point(ctlpos.X - 2, ctlpos.Y + ctl.Height - 2) 'then locate its position
Me.show
```